# How to read email within a PST compacted by Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

After running out of space on gmail, I downloaded all emails to the desktop using POP3 with Thunderbird as the client application. Whilst downloading the emails, on two occasions Thunderbird asked to  compact the PST file. This option was accepted.

After all emails were downloaded, some of the mails loaded during the period for which mails were compacted are no longer fully available. By this I mean a general search  (sender address, subject etc) from Thunderbird displays the email sought. Yet when I drill down into any particular email, the email is not displayed.

Using Thunderbird, how do I read any particular email that is part of a compacted PST?

Comment: Compacting a PST file should be done by Outlook, not Thunderbird. If you cannot read the PST file, try a trial version of Stellar Tools and see if you can repair the file for Outlook to read.

Comment: It was Thunderberg that said the PST file was large, and should be compacted. Outlook was nowhere in the picture.

Comment: That may be, but PST is a proprietary Outlook file, not a Thunderbird file (so far as I know)

Comment: Next time, you can use takeout.google.com

Comment: @Gantendo: How would that help? After downloading the mails from Google directly, a mail client would still be needed to actually use those mails for future communication. As soon as a mail client were to enter the picture (as in my case Thunderbird), sooner or later the mail client would recommend compacting (or similar mechanism) given the volume.

Comment: Because Google Takeout produces a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox mbox file instead of PST

Comment: It's not so much about "_should_ be done", but rather, I'm curious how you loaded a PST into Thunderbird _at all_? Thunderbird does not even use that format, all it supports is mbox and Maildir...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the comments, I think, here is a general confusion about the acronym "PST":

PST is "reserved" by Outlook as its internal local mail storage format.
Thunderbird doesn't handle this format and will not create it.

*=> So I'm sure you've not seen "PST" in Thunderbird but talk about something like "mail folder".*

---

Depending on the configuration, Thunderbird should have created files in the "mbox"-format while the mail download via POP3. Additional to the mbox formatted mail file an index-file (*.msf) is created aside. In the simplest form you have the files:

```sh
INBOX       # visible as the INBOX folder
INBOX.msf   # the associated index file
```

If Thunderbird asks to "compact" a mail folder (not PST), then this is similar to a database action to compact:
When deleting mails, these mails are only "marked as deleted". By "compacting" these marked mails will be physically removed (the mbox file will be rewritten without the deleted files and the index file gets recreated).

=> So there is no way to find your missing mails in a "compacted" mail folder if they are not visible anymore in the "normal" view. They are not present anymore in this mbox file.

You can test their presence by searching some keywords in the file "INBOX" at the command-line. The file you'll find here:

```sh
# Linux:
~/.thunderbird/<cryptic-id>.default/Mail/<mailaccount>/INBOX

# Windows:
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\<cryptic-id>.default-release-1\Mail\<mailaccount>\INBOX
```

---

Probably you will say: *"I didn't delete any mails."*

This might be true and is plausible: Thunderbird in its default settings will archive mails of a distinctive age. — As you moved a huge mail history from Google to the local Thunderbird, there surly will be several matured mails that probably immediately got archived.

This achieving process means:

1. Copy the mail to the "Archive" (another file in mbox format)
2. Delete the mail from the "INBOX" (mark as deleted)
3. As the trigger value has been reached after several of these moves, Thundebird asks for "Compact the mail folders?" and removes the "marked as deleted" mails frome the INBOX file.

*=> I would expect that you will find your missing mails in Thunderbird's "Archive" folder, located nearby the "INBOX" and the other default folders like "Trash" and "Sent".*

If this scenario turns out to be your solution and you don't like it, then I would suggest you

1. switch off the "Archive" feature in *"Account Settings » Copies & Foders"*.
2. Then you can sort your archived mails to the place you want them to be.

Comment: Your answer definitely helps although if those mails are utterly gone... . Unfortunately if Thunderbird is incapable of creating a PST stream, I've no idea *how* that came about. I'll try to get a screenshot from that particular device, and post a link here. Let me try the rest of your steps, and if that works I'll accept your answer as the right one. TY muchly! (Y)